# How to change the color of letter present at first index in rich textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to change the color of letter present at first index in rich textbox. But my code is not working. I am using getpositionatoffset form 0 index to 1, Here is my code  :

C#

```
TextSelection ts = box1.Selection;
TextPointer tp = box1.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(0);
TextPointer tpe = box1.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(1);
ts.Select(tp, tpe);
ts.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new  SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
```

If I change the value of GetPositionAtOffset(1) to GetPositionAtOffset(3) It will start working. I don't why it is happening.

XAML :

```
<RichTextBox   Name="box1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <FlowDocument Name="flowdoc">
            <Paragraph Name="para" >I am a flow document. Would you like to edit me?</Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your document contains more than text. There are FlowDocument and Paragraph. So `GetPositionAtOffset(0)` returns the flowdocument opening instead of the first letter.
To get the first character you must move forward until you find a text element:

```
TextPointer position = box1.Document.ContentStart;
while (position != null)
{
    if (position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
    {
        TextPointer start = position.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);
        TextPointer end = position.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Backward);
        new TextRange(start, end).ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
        break;
    }
    position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
}
```